# How to prevent my android app from sniffing?

Tags: android, security, ssl, encryption

I have an api based application.

I already use ssl but I need a more secure way.

For example the Wireshark grab all api calls!

Comment: If Wireshark is able to grab all API calls you are not using HTTPS or you have installed the server's private key in Wireshark.

Comment: I already used https but wireshark will grab calls. Take a look here please https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116557

Comment: certificate pinning?

Comment: what you mean certificate pinning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certificate pinning is technology you need. You have to say your application what is ssl certificate of api server. Configure it using `network_security_config.xml`. Using this way your application be much harder to be attacked by mitm.

Comment: Thanks, but decompiling app will reveal all xml contetnts for hackers! Isn't it?

Comment: Even with attacker find a way to extract certificate from apk, he can't just take it and attach to his website. It is going to break https and connection won't be established.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, can  you suggest a good tutorial about it. I am not familier with Certificate pinning. I need to be familier with that and then use it.

Comment: You can find few just by typing "Android Certificate Pinning" but this one shows few ways of implementing this feature https://medium.com/@appmattus/android-security-ssl-pinning-1db8acb6621e

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways that you can try out to make secure your apps:

1. Certificate Pinning
2. Token Based Authentication
3. basic Auth
4. Theft Detection

**1.Certificate Pining :**

Obtain a certificate from your server and attach it to your each HTTP request. if your certificate is valid then only your request will proceed.

**2. Token Based Authentication :**
   Your server will provide a token. use this token every time when you make HTTP request.

**3. basic Auth :**

Use basic auth with each your request:

4. **Theft Detection**

Use key based Encryption techniques like AES, and generate this key dynamically  from your server.